# How to create a valid 2D array that Google Apps Script Form will accept for Checkbox grid question response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am getting values from a sheet and needing to convert the values into a 2D array that will then be accepted by .createResponse() of Google Forms.  In the spreadsheet, the values for cell[0] = Paris, NYC and cell[1] = LA.  I have tried this function:

```
function testFunction1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const form = FormApp.openByUrl(ss.getFormUrl());
  var arr = [];
  for(i = 0; i<2; i++){
    var cell = ss.getRange(2,i+2).getValue();
    cell = cell.split(',');
    arr.push(cell);
  }
  var newRes = form
    .getItems()[0]
    .asCheckboxGridItem()
    .createResponse(arr);
  form.createResponse().withItemResponse(newRes).submit();
}
```

When I split each cell, I get:
split cell[0] = ['Paris', 'NYC']
split cell[1] = ['LA']

After pushing the items into arr, I get:
arr = [ ['Paris', 'NYC'], ['LA'] ]

This looks like a 2D array but then .createResponse(arr) gives the error of "Exception: Invalid response submitted to checkbox grid question."

If I manually enter [ ['Paris', 'NYC'], ['LA'] ] into the .createResponse like this:

```
function testFunction2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const form = FormApp.openByUrl(ss.getFormUrl());
  var newRes = form
    .getItems()[0]
    .asCheckboxGridItem()
    .createResponse([ ['Paris','NYC'], ['LA'] ]);
  form.createResponse().withItemResponse(newRes).submit();
}
```

then there is no error and the response is added to the Form correctly.

I have also tried:

```
function testFunction1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const form = FormApp.openByUrl(ss.getFormUrl());
  var arr = [[]];
  for(i = 0; i<2; i++){
    var cell = ss.getRange(2,i+2).getValue();
    cell = cell.split(',');
    arr[0][i] = cell;
    console.log(cell);
  }
  var cell = arr;
  console.log(cell[0]);
  var newRes = form
    .getItems()[0]
    .asCheckboxGridItem()
    .createResponse(cell[0]);
  form.createResponse().withItemResponse(newRes).submit();
}
```

This throws the error of "Exception: Invalid response submitted to checkbox grid question." at the .createResponse(cell[0]).

Also if the .createResponse(cell[0]) is changed to .createResponse(cell), then the following error is received, "Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for FormApp.CheckboxGridItem.createResponse."

I also used typeof of the manually typed item, cell values, and resulting arrays and they all come up as object.  What am I doing wrong?

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the situation that `.createResponse([ ['Paris','NYC'], ['LA'] ]);` works and `cell[0] = Paris, NYC and cell[1] = LA` in your question, I'm worried that each value of `arr` might have a space. This is just my guess. So in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
cell = cell.split(',');
```

#### To:

```
cell = cell.split(',').map(e => e.trim());
```

or,

#### From:

```
var arr = [];
for(i = 0; i<2; i++){
  var cell = ss.getRange(2,i+2).getValue();
  cell = cell.split(',');
  arr.push(cell);
}
```

#### To:

```
var arr = ss.getRange(2, 2, 1, 2).getValues()[0].map(c => c.split(",").map(e => e.trim()));
```

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)

Comment: The second edit was the solution.  Just adding in trim resulted in the same errors but using the var arr = ss..... line did the trick.  So, it sounds as though, trailing spaces were being added in somewhere (the original data doesn't have them - I did check) and by trimming all of the values at the same time was the answer.  Thanks @Tanaike!

Comment: @ADOrch Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.